# queue files corruption in MQ in circular logging

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using circular logging.  Because of human intervention, one of the
queue files is corrupted.

Since the circular logging is not having the ability of recovering the 
corrupted queue files, what will be the next steps it will take?

Will queue manager create an empty queue file for that queue and start
enrolling the messages to it? Else, it will just show the pending
messages in the queue but not allow the applications to process?

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly note, MQ cannot recover from a damaged queue file when it is configured for circular logging.

> Will queue manager create an empty queue file for that queue and start enrolling the messages to it? Else, it will just show the pending messages in the queue but not allow the applications to process?

None of the above.  The queue manager will return an error to any process attempting to access that queue.

When a queue file is damaged, it may or may not have had messages in it.  There is no automatic recovery possible that would correctly reconcile the state of any messages that may have been enqueued, therefore no further processing is done on that queue and any access returns an error.  Human intervention is required in that case and the fix is to delete and redefine the queue using `runmqsc`.

If additional queue recovery is required to make sure messages are not lost in such cases, linear logging is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks Rob, It is really helpful. I will make sure of recreating the queue in the case of damaged queue file.

Answer (score 1):

The queue manager is not going to create an new queue file automatically.  If you truly have a corrupted queue then you may have to delete and recreate it.  It would be helpful if you can provide more info about the error you see indicating the queue is corrupt. Also, what version of MQ are you using?

Comment: Hello Valerie, 

I haven't encountered this issue, it had spotted in my mind when I was reading about the logging in MQ. So I am asking generically. If needs to be manually removed, how come admin comes to know about the corrupted queue file left overs? lets say we deleted it, how does queue manager detects that it can create a new queue file?

Comment: In my past experience if you delete the file, you can make a dummy "q" file and copy that over to the directory the recycle the qmgr.   However, this is a very tricky situation... especially if this is production.  Queues do not become corruption except in an extremely rare circumstance.